# OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use (Python program hosted by public server)

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, frontend, web-hosting

I am sorry. I have done python before, but hosting a python program in a webserver is a new thing I am learning. Your help will be much appreciated.

My aim is to host a pyhton program in a webpage such that user can give a set of inputs. Based on the inputs python program does some calculation and provides an output to the user. This whole thing is running fine on windows. In windows what I am doing is: I run cmd and 
I type C:\Python34\python.exe -m http.server 8020
Then I run the python program (most important part is provided below) and it starts:
"serving at port
Server Starts - localhost:8020"

Then from chrome I type: http://127.0.0.1:8000, provide the input and get the output.

I have the same directory structure in the webserver (based on centos). However, I cannot run both http.server and python program as it gives the OSerror when I run the second one from the same port. How can I tackle this?

I am posting the javascript code first and then the python program.
When I run in the webpage, I get 404 error from inspect element of chrome.

```
<script>
function submitReq() {
 // alert("calling post");
  var singleValues = $( "#single" ).val();
  var payload = {};
  payload["Seq"] = $("#seq").val();
  payload["Mut_Seq"] = $("#mut_seq").val();
  payload["Ct"] = parseInt($("#ct").val());
  payload["Sodium_con"] = parseInt($("#sodium_con").val());
 // alert(JSON.stringify(payload));
   $.post("/getDNAsequence",
        JSON.stringify(payload),
        function(data,status){
        var res = data.replace(new RegExp("\n", 'g'), " <br/> ");
            $("#output").html(res);
        });

};

$("#submit").click(submitReq);
</script>
```

---

```
class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self) :
        if (self.path == "/"):
            with open ("dna.html", "r") as myfile:
                data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '\n')
                self.wfile.write(bytes(data, "utf-8"))
    def do_POST(self):

        if(self.path=="/getDNAsequence"):
            content_len = int(self.headers.get('content-length', 0))
            post_body = self.rfile.read(content_len)
            parsed_json = json.loads(post_body.decode("utf-8"))
            Seq = parsed_json['Seq']
            Mut_Seq = parsed_json['Mut_Seq']
            Ct = parsed_json['Ct']
            Sodium_con = parsed_json['Sodium_con']
            baal = Forward_mamapcr_primer(Seq, Mut_Seq, Ct, Sodium_con)
            self.wfile.write(bytes(baal, "utf-8"))

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

def main():    
    hostName = "localhost"
    hostPort = 8020

    print ("serving at port")
    myServer = HTTPServer((hostName, hostPort), MyServer)
    print( "Server Starts - %s:%s" % (hostName, hostPort))

    try:
        myServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    myServer.server_close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cgi-bin of apache server to run python script with user provided parameters.

Comment: Using cgi-bin solved the hosting problem. Still not sure why json script did not work. But, thank you boss.

Comment: Kindly elaborate. I can help you out